# I have a service, it's generate toolBar, there are a few classes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, service

class menu

```
import { QueryParam } from "./query-param";
import { QueryRouterLink } from "./query-router-link";


export class Menu {
  link: string;
  name: string;
  queryParam: QueryParam[];
  queryRouterLink?: QueryRouterLink;
}
```

class QueryParam

```
export class QueryParam {
  name: string;
  value: string;
}
```

class QueryRouterLink

```
export class QueryRouterLink {
  [name: string]: string;
}
```

my service

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Menu } from "../classes/menu";
import { QueryParam } from "../classes/query-param";
import { QueryRouterLink } from "../classes/query-router-link";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class LinksService {
  constructor() {}

  queryRouterLink: QueryRouterLink;

  autoMenu() {
    let myMenu: Menu[] = [
      {
        link: `/componentOne`,
        name: "ComponentOne",
        queryParam: [{ name: "resource", value: "ComponentOne" }],
      },
      {
        link: `/componentTwo`,
        name: "ComponentTwo",
        queryParam: [{ name: "resource", value: "ComponentTwo" }],
      },
    ];

    for (let menuItem of myMenu) {
      menuItem.queryRouterLink = this.getCorrectQueryParam(
        menuItem.queryParam as QueryParam[]
      );
    }

    return myMenu;
  }

  getCorrectQueryParam(queryParam: QueryParam[]) {
    for (let param of queryParam) {
      this.queryRouterLink[param.name] = param.value;
    }
    return this.queryRouterLink;
  }
}
```

getCorrectQueryParam convert my queryParam[name: 'resource', value: "ComponentTwo"] to usual QueryParams [name: string]: string;
error in console is Cannot set property 'resource' of undefined.
is it mean that name is undefined? Or my function work wrong?

my app.html

```
  <mat-toolbar>
      <h1
        *ngFor="let item of menu"
        [routerLink]="item.link"
        [queryParams]="item.queryRouterLink"
      >
        {{ item.name }}
      </h1>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

my app.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { LinksService } from "./services/links.service";
import { Menu } from "./classes/menu";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.scss"],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = "training";
  menu: Menu[];

  constructor(private linkS: LinksService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.menu = this.linkS.autoMenu();
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you would have got more responses if you had posted a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt. Right now this is too much code to review and provide any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Menu } from "../classes/menu";
import { QueryParam } from "../classes/query-param";
import { QueryRouterLink } from "../classes/query-router-link";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class LinksService {
  constructor() {}

  queryRouterLink: QueryRouterLink;  <===== wrong

  autoMenu() {
    let myMenu: Menu[] = [
      {
        link: `/componentOne`,
        name: "ComponentOne",
        queryParam: [{ name: "resource", value: "ComponentOne" }],
      },
      {
        link: `/componentTwo`,
        name: "ComponentTwo",
        queryParam: [{ name: "resource", value: "ComponentTwo" }],
      },
    ];

    for (let menuItem of myMenu) {
      menuItem.queryRouterLink = this.getCorrectQueryParam(
        menuItem.queryParam as QueryParam[]
      );
    }

    return myMenu;
  }

  getCorrectQueryParam(queryParam: QueryParam[]) {
    let queryRouterLink: QueryRouterLink = {}; <====correct 
    for (let param of queryParam) {
      this.queryRouterLink[param.name] = param.value;
    }
    return this.queryRouterLink;
  }
}
```